# Matrix Transformation of a Polynomial (Linear Algebra)

Tags: polynomials

I'm having trouble understanding matrix representations of polynomials. The question in particular is:

T: P2 (R)-> P2(R) defined by T(f(x))= f"(x) +2f'(x) - f(x).

I know for this question we have to use the standard bases of 2 degree polynomials, b={1,x,x^2}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check what $T$ does to the basis vectors $\{1, x, x^2\}$:
$$
T(1) = -1 = -1\cdot + 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x^2
$$
$$
T(x) = 2 - x = 2\cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot x + 0\cdot x^2
$$
$$
T(x^2) = 2 + 4x - x^2 = 2\cdot 1 + 4\cdot x + (-1)\cdot x^2
$$
Now treat your basis like you would the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ - can you write down the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis?

Comment: Therefore, the matrix corresponding to the Linear Transformation on the standard basis is: -1 2 2 (row 1) 0 -1 4 (row 2) 0 0 -1 (Row 3). Thank you so much, your explanation made it so much clearer!